# Inserting large number of hierarchical data using Spring

Tags: java, oracle, spring

first of all, let me say that I'm a total JAVA newbie. But I have this problem. I need to insert data in to a set of parent child tables. The data structure looks this

data item 1 - (level 1 data)
 
     data item 1.1 - (level 2 data)
     data item 1.2
data item 2
     data item 2.1
     data item 2.2
          data item 2.2.1 - (level 3 data)
          data item 2.2.2
data item 3...

There are 3 tables in Oracle.
Level1_Data_Table(Level_1_ID, name, etc...)
Level2_Data_Table(Level_2_ID, Level_1_ID, name, etc...)
Level3_Data_Table(Level_3_ID, Level_1_ID, name, etc...)

There could be thousands or Level 1, Level 2, and Level 3 data.

The IDs are from level1Seq.nextVal, level2Seq.nextVal, level3Seq.nextVal.

How can I do a batch insert a batch insert for level 1 data, get all the IDs and use it to do a batch insert of level 2, and do the same for level 3?

Currently I'm using Spring's jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate to do the inserts. But it's super slow. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the exact Class name and package. I can't find batchUpdate in the Spring javadoc. Do you know the javadoc url?

Comment: Below is the link. It's a method of the JDBCTemplate class. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#batchUpdate(java.lang.String, org.springframework.jdbc.core.BatchPreparedStatementSetter)

Comment: the batchUpdate() method should be an efficient way of inserting many rows. But how do you determine the values the sequences generate?

Answer (score 0):

PL/SQL has a RETURNING construct that can return all ID values as an array. There is Oracle documentation that describes how you pass arrays. I did it once with Spring.

Comment: Do you mean writing a PL/SQL stored procedure instead of having the SQL INSERT INTO in JAVA? So, in the JAVA code, call the SP, and pass in the values in an Array to Oracle?

Comment: Yes, insert the array with a FORALL and have it tell you the sequence values with a returning clause. I've never tried this exact combination but it's worth a try.

Comment: the Oracle jdbc documentation is in document b14355.pdf for 10g Release 2. Use the setPlsqlIndexTable() method in OraclePreparedStatement to bind IN prams. Use registerIndexTableOutParameter() to bind out parameters. As for Spring, I think I used the StoredProcedure object in the jdbc.object package. But I'm sure you can use JdbcTemplate.